# How to set and speak multiple language in a sentence for TextToSpeech in Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am developing TextToSpeech in Android. I use the following code and it work fine.

```
public void EnableTextToSpeech(){
        //TextToSpeech
        text_to_speech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    Log.d(TAG,"TextToSpeech init SUCCESS");
                    int result = text_to_speech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    text_to_speech.setPitch(1);
                    text_to_speech.setSpeechRate(1);

                    if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                        Log.d(TAG,"TextToSpeech NOT SUPPORT");
                    }else {
                        Log.d(TAG,"TextToSpeech Enable");
                            String welcome = "Welcome";
                            text_to_speech.speak(welcome , TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,"TEST");
                    }
                }else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"TextToSpeech init FAIL");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But I want it to speak the multiple language like **Chines** and **English** in one sentence.

Can I set different language like the following code?

```
text_to_speech.setLanguage(Locale.CHINESE);
text_to_speech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```

**How to set and speak multiple language in a sentence for `TextToSpeech` in Android ?**

Comment: you want same sentence to be spoken twice, once in Chinese and then English? Why don't you pass the language as a parameter to EnableTextToSpeech method

Comment: @sandy From what I understand, no. He wants to mix both languages while speaking the sentence. Meaning multiple languages in the same sentence.

I don't know the API for TextToSpeech but I guess he has to train a datamodel for that use case? Machine learning like for OCR?

Comment: @Nico in that case, he needs to specify at what point his API should switch from one language to other

Comment: Yes , @Nico. I want to mix both languages while speaking the sentence. Meaning multiple languages in the same sentence. For example , the sample sentence is look like : I want to go to 日本(the word means Japan).

Comment: The idea itself is genious. I would love an app that is able to do something like this when traveling. High potential for this app. But it is also a very hard task. You have to find an algorithm that detects a change of language in the sentence it receives and then switched to the detected language. I guess for this part a training model really needs to come in place. But I am a novice in this topic.